# JPA NamedQuery use with aggregation functions and group by

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I have several records on my database table Foo and I need to aggregate a column to sum its values.

The entity that represents the table is this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "FOO")
@NamedQueries({
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.total", query = "SELECT f.id, sum(f.someInt) AS 
SOME_INT, f.parentId FROM Foo f where f.parentId = 'root' group by 
p.parentId"),
@NamedQuery(name = "Foo.findAll", query = "SELECT f from Foo f") })
public class Foo {

@Id
@Column(name = "ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String id;

@Column(name = "PARENT_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private String parentId;

@Column(name = "SOME_INT", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Integer someInt;

public Foo() {
}
```

}

And if I call this on my dao service bean:

```
entityManager.createNamedQuery("Foo.total", Foo.class).getResultList();
```

I get this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create TypedQuery for query with more than one return using requested result type [Foo]
```

It seems that JPA cannot match the return values to the object Foo. If is that so, how can I make this to work?

If I call the other @NamedQuery "Foo.findAll" it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT f.id, sum(f.someInt) AS SOME_INT, f.parentId FROM Foo f 
where f.parentId = 'root' group by p.parentId"
```

This query doesn't return a Foo entity but a projection instead.

You might want to create a custom POJO with the attributes you are selecting and use that as a return type when creating the query.

See [this](http://blog.arnoldgalovics.com/2017/03/14/using-projections-in-your-data-access-layer/) and [this link](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#criteria-typedquery-wrapper).